# What are the solutions of $x=\cot x$?

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry

Need to find intervals in which the function $y=\frac{x}{2}\cdot \cos x$ is increasing and decreasing. I tried to solve it on the way below but don't know how to continue.

$ \\ 
y=\frac{x}{2}\cdot \cos x,\ x\in (0,2\pi)\\
y=\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\cdot \cos x \\
{y}'=({\frac{1}{2}\cdot x\cdot \cos x})' \\
{y}'=\frac{1}{2}\cdot ({x\cdot \cos x})' \\
{y}'=\frac{1}{2}\cdot ({x}'\cdot \cos x+x\cdot (\cos x)') \\
{y}'=\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\cos x-x\cdot \sin x) \\
{y}'=0 \\
\frac{1}{2}\cdot(\cos x-x\cdot \sin x)=0 \\ $ 
$\hspace{1cm}$
$\\
\cos x-x\cdot \sin x=0\ /(\cos x) \\
1-x\cdot \tan x=0 \\
-x\cdot \tan x=-1 \\
x\cdot \tan x=1 \\
x=\frac{1}{\tan x} \\
x=\cot x $

Comment: To my knowledge, the equation $x=\cot(x)$ can only be solved by numerical methods.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it? @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: See the hint provided by @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

The roots are close to the vertical asymptotes of the cotangent, occurring at $x=k\pi$.

To get a first approximation, we can linearize the cotangent close to a root and

$$\cot x-x\approx\frac1{x-k\pi}-x=0.$$

The positive solution is

$$x=\frac{k\pi+\sqrt{k^2\pi^2+4}}{2}.$$

From this, you start Newton's iterations, which will quickly converge.

Though a bit cluttered, the plot below shows you how the hyperbolas match the true curve close to the roots:

[image]

Comment: I get 2 solutions for x: $
 x_{1}=\frac{\pi}{6} \ and \
 x_{2}=\frac{5\pi}{6}.  
$  
Is it correct? @YvesDaoust

Comment: @Mathlearner: there are infinitely many solutions. I don't know how you computed these two values but they aren't solutions.

Comment: I'll try again. Thank you so much. @YvesDaoust

Answer (score 3):

It is a transcendental equation and you will have to find the solution numerically.

Comment: Can you explain why it's transcendental?

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips because trig functions are transcendental?

Comment: Can you show how to get to a numerically solution and what are the solutions for x in my problem? @PaulChilds

Comment: @JohnGlenn I'm not sure - is that a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0):

Considering instead the function $$f(x)=\cos(x)-x\sin(x)$$

its solutions can be very well approximated developing $f(x)$ as a Taylor series built around $x=n \pi$ and using later series reversion. This gives for $n>0$
$$x_{n+1}=q+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{4}{3 q^3}+\frac{53}{15 q^5}-\frac{1226}{105
   q^7}+\frac{13597}{315 q^9}-\frac{65782}{385
   q^{11}}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^{13}}\right)$$ where $\color{red}{q=n \pi}$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 3.42544796823 &  3.42561845948 \\
 2 & 6.43729815231 &  6.43729817917 \\
 3 & 9.52933440522 &  9.52933440536 \\
 4 & 12.6452872239 &  12.6452872239 \\
 5 & 15.7712848748 &  15.7712848748
\end{array}
\right)$$

Concerning the first root, we can approximate it building the $[2,2p]$ Padé approximant and, depending on $p$, the **square** of the *approximate* solution will correspond to the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{2}{3},\frac{36}{49},\frac{1470}{1987},\frac{111272}{150337},\frac{1353
   0330}{18279971},\frac{2412956172}{3259985969},\frac{593317446358}{801591982115}
   \right\}$$